# Extract the text out of Illustrator file any API or script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm working on a project that has 1000 files with the same typo ex. the file with the word "dogs" that has to be turned into "dog". these 1000 files has the same typo. Is there anyway that I can write a script to do that in Illustrator? or some API that I can extract out text from the file then edit it (change from "dogs" into "dog") then save it back because I don't want to open 1000 files and do it 1000 times.

Comment: is word "dogs" is a text layer?

Comment: yes it is in a text layer but nested in other layer.

Comment: This script doesn't do exactly what you want, but if you're willing to wrangle the script to do what you want, it's already like 90% there: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10364559#10364559 - You could perhaps make an Action where you run the script and then run it on all of your documents in batch. - Gotta say this is the first time I've seen a script with a "donate" dialog.

Answer (score 3):

**This script will find keyword "Dogs" and replace it with "Dog" within all open documents**

```
    #target illustrator
    var count;
var folderRef = Folder.selectDialog ("choose Folder");
var prefix = prompt("Prefix name","");
var fileRef = folderRef + "/" + prefix;
for (count=0;count<9999;count++){
    var temp;
    if(count<10){
        temp = "000";
        }else if(count>=10 && count<100){
        temp = "00";
        }else if(count>=100 && count<1000){
        temp = "0";
        }else{
            temp = "";
            }
    var result = fileRef + " " + temp + count;
    var f = new File(result + ".ai");
    if ( f.exists ) {
        app.open( new File(f) );
for(var i = 0; i < app.documents.length; i++){    
    for(var j = 0; j < app.documents[i].textFrames.length; j++){    
        var str = app.documents[i].textFrames[j].contents;    
        var rep = str.replace ("Dogs", "Dog");
        app.documents[i].textFrames[j].contents = rep;
//justification lines
       var z = app.documents[i].textFrames[j].paragraphs[0].paragraphAttributes;
       z.justification = Justification.CENTER; 
          } 
    }
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);   //comment this lineby putting "//" before it if you wanna keep your file open after edited
    }

}
```

so if you want to replace word from all open document you can use this; save this code as `ReplaceTest(orWhatever).jsx` then put it in your script folder,and restart your Illustrator . you will find your script at `File-Scripts`.

[image]

Comment your requirement below for further improvements in code :) you can see how i achieved it; don't forget to comment close command if you wanna keep your file open

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so so much for your help Design Phoenix, I would like 2 more improvements, 1. I want it to report to me which document has been edited and which one are not since some file contents the word dog and some aren't I would like to get a list of file being edited. 2. can I specify the folder path and let it automate every file in that folder without me open 100 files manually? I'm using MacOS. thank you so much for your support

Comment: if you have folder than can you tell me file pattern like test_1 test_2 etc?

Comment: Newyork 0244, Newyork 0245, Newyork 0246, Newyork 0247

California 2230, California 2231, California 2232

something like this.
thank you so so much for your help.

Comment: well will it be okay if you type Newyork once and it edit all your Newyork named files?

Comment: that would be great too.

Comment: okay i'm trying :)

Comment: I tried your script and it works properly except after it replace the text, it indent the text to the left. Can the script only replace the text and not indent text to the left?

Comment: I tried with plain text file it works perfectly but when I use it in an actual file it's not only replace text but indent to the left too. Maybe it's because the text object layer is nested inside another object. Is there a way to turn this effect off?

Comment: don't sure but see my edited answer

Comment: I edited my answer and yes there must be way to keep font in centre; so is your font allignment is changing to left???

Comment: @user136301 Tested and now my scripts changing all texts justification to middle center :) and sorry since my duty time over so if you will have further issues i'm afraid you'll have to wait for 8 hours :(

Comment: Is it working for you? if it's solved your problem don't forget to mark answer as accepted :)

Comment: Still no response @user136301 if answer worked for you then please mark it as accepted so others can also know that your problem is resolved :)